# EF6 Code first with PostgreSQL database throws exception. (PostgresException: 42P01: relation "public.Authors" does not exist)

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-6

I am using PostgreSQL database with EF6 code first approach, but I am getting the following exception.

```
PostgresException: 42P01: relation "public.Authors" does not exist
```

Here are the model and context class.

```
public class BookStore : DbContext
{
    public BookStore() : base(nameOrConnectionString: "Default")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
    }

    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

I have specified the schema which is public in my case, but when inserting the same data I am getting the exception.

```
using (var context = new BookStore())
{
    var authors = new List<Author>
    {
        new Author
        {
            FirstName ="Carson",
            LastName ="Alexander",
            BirthDate = DateTime.Parse("1985-09-01"),
            Books = new List<Book>()
            {
                new Book { Title = "Introduction to Machine Learning"},
                new Book { Title = "Advanced Topics in Machine Learning"},
                new Book { Title = "Introduction to Computing"}
            }
        }
    };

    context.Authors.AddRange(authors);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The Generated SQL looks like this.

```
Opened connection at 7/1/2019 2:39:45 PM +05:00

Started transaction at 7/1/2019 2:39:45 PM +05:00

INSERT INTO "public"."Authors"("FirstName","LastName","BirthDate") VALUES (@p_0,@p_1,@p_2) RETURNING "AuthorId"


-- p_0: 'Carson' (Type = Object, IsNullable = false)

-- p_1: 'Alexander' (Type = Object, IsNullable = false)

-- p_2: '9/1/1985 12:00:00 AM' (Type = DateTime, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 7/1/2019 2:39:45 PM +05:00

-- Failed in 7 ms with error: 42P01: relation "public.Authors" does not exist

Closed connection at 7/1/2019 2:39:45 PM +05:00
```

The exception is thrown when SaveChanges is called. How to handle this and what is wrong with my code? Any suggestions.

Comment: I don't see where you actually provide any table names in there or where the SQL is generated, but `"public.Authors"` should most probably be `public."Authors"`

Comment: Added the generated SQL above